# logic app check who has read a yammer post

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, yammer

I'm looking at the Logic Apps [Yammer connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/yammer/).
When we put a message on Yammer we want to find out who has read it.  Is there a way to find a list of people in a Yammer group who have not read a Yammer message?
If it can't be done in Logic Apps, is there another way to do it?

As a workaround, I'm trying to do this on the basis of who has liked a message and have done this in Logic apps.  It gives a message that the response is not in JSON format.  Also, it gives me the number of likes rather than a list of people who have liked it.
[image]

This is what I put into the HTTP request

[image]

After our chat  I tried this
[image]

and this

[image]

and got this error message.

"error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: d41c78c7-afa5-405f-8f52-8b587ecf1a00\r\nCorrelation ID: 9ffd2247-78ca-4be2-8111-c17a95a830d6\r\nTimestamp: 2020-01-23 10:09:55Z",
  "error_codes": [
    900144
  ]

I also tried putting in my Azure directory id in place of tenant id.  It failed with and without the directory id.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there isn't an action in logic app Yammer connector which can get the list of users in a group who haven't read a message. And I checked all of the rest api in Yammer api [document](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/rest-api-rate-limits). Just find a rest [api](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/usersin_groupidjson) which can get the users in a group:

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/in_group/:Group_Id.json
```

So I think neither yammer rest api nor logic app can not implement this requirement of get the list of users in a group who haven't read a message.

**Update:**

For your question about how to implement the workaround in logic app, as I don't have yammer app and account, so I can just provide some suggestions for your reference.

Since the yammer actions in logic app are very limited, so we can just use yammer Apis in logic according to [HTTP action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#add-an-http-action).

First we need to get access token from yammer, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2) and refer to the `C. App Authentication` title in it. Put this post url in HTTP action in logic app and get the response body. Parse the response body and get the `token` property under the `access_token` property. Then we can use this token in the apis which we will call in the next HTTP actions.

Then, call this [api](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/usersliked_messagemessage_idjson) in HTTP action(choose "Get" as the method) with the token which we got above to get the users who like the message, the url should be like this:

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/liked_message/:Message_id.json?access_token=<<ACCESSTOKEN>>
```

Get the response body(and parse it in json type in array) from the api above and then call the other [api](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/usersin_groupidjson) in HTTP action(with access token) to get the users in one group. Also get the response body from it and parse it in json type and store in array.

After that, use two nested "For each" actions in logic app to loop the two array and compare them. Then we can get the result which you want.

**Update 2:**

[image]

Comment: As a workaround, we could ask people to like messages that they have read.  Could I use this to find out who has liked a message then compare with the entire group.https://developer.yammer.com/docs/usersliked_messagemessage_idjson

Comment: @AlHal Yes, I think it can be a workaround. But if the number of users in the group is very large, it may not be a good solution if we need to loop all of the users who like message to compare with the entire group.

Comment: I think the number of users is small.  How can I do this in logic apps?

Comment: Hi @AlHal, as I don't have yammer app and account, so for your requirement I can just provide some suggestions for your reference. I update my answer, please check it.

Comment: I tried putting these URLs into my HTTP request   https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[:client_id]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[:redirect_uri]       https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token?client_id=[:client_id]&client_secret=[:client_secret]&code=[:code]&grant_type=authorization_code  The second used a post method.  Why did they fail?

Comment: @AlHal Could you please provide a screenshot for the http action request the url in your logic app ? Please erase sensitive information of your request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206502/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-alhal).

Comment: Hi @AlHal In our chat yesterday I didn't mean you need to copy the request in the screenshot I provided. I mean you can just refer to it to request the yammer oauth2 url to get its access token. Please refer to the new screenshot in my answer in "Update2".

Comment: I copied the request in your screenshot and it said invalid application.  The tutorial says the following:  "client_id and redirect_uri are available in the app that you registered. The redirect_uri should match the Redirect URI entered in the app registration page."  I didn't register an app.  Yammer is just available on our intranet homepage which is based on Sharepoint.  I went to account settings, but did not see a client_id field.  Would you know where to find it or do I not need it?

Comment: Hope you had a good weekend.  I apologise if I have misunderstood you.  Would it be possible to supply template text and puts in dots where I need to substitute something confidential?

Comment: @AlHal Have you got the access token successfully ?

Comment: Afraid I haven't.

Comment: @AlHal So what's the problem while you request the url for access token ?

Comment: I get the message Invalid client application.  This is the URI.   https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token   Header  {
  "Content_Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
} body  client_id=[:client_id]&client_secret=[:client_secret]&code=[:code]&grant_type=authorization_code

Comment: @AlHal Ok, I think you can do the steps of getting the access token in other tools but not logic app(Maybe it is easier for us to do it). Just follow the Yammer [tutorial](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2) to get the access token in other tools(such as postman...) and then go to logic app to use this access token to request the Yammer api in "HTTP" action.

Comment: Our Intranet is Sharepoint based.  I log in with my windows ID and the Intranet comes up straight away without needing to log in.  Yammer is just one of the options available.  Therefore, when the tutorial talks about click sign in with Yammer, I don't know what it means.

Comment: Perhaps this sheds light on what I'm saying  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/yammer-blog/yammer-api-auth-with-files-in-sharepoint-online/ba-p/834874

Comment: @AlHal I'm sorry that I also not familiar with Yammer, so I can just provide some suggestions which I think might be useful :)

Comment: That is fine.  I appreciate all the help you have given me.  Have a great evening.